# com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to use Java Google Drive API.
I tried this code:

```
public Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, URISyntaxException
    {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("sonoratestw-226@sonora-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File("C:\\buffer\\sonora project-3256770463ed.p12"))
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN))
            .setServiceAccountUser("sonoratestw@gmail.com")
            .build();

        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, null)
            .setApplicationName("FileListAccessProject")
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

        return service;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
An error occurred: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
```

I use this configuration:

[image]

Can you give some idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I don't think you can use setServiceAccountUser unless its a domain admin account and you have added the service account to the admin account and the user in question is also a user on the admin account.

Comment: Can you give the total error and exception it is throwing?

Comment: Have you found the solution? Please provide your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277025), one reason that you get the error 401 is that the service account you are using doesn't have access to the drive account associated with your Gmail address. So if you want to be able to access the files it uploads you must grant yourself access to them though the service account.

Here are the other SO questions that I think can help you to understand more the service account

- [google oauth2 impersonate service account with user@gmail.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510138/google-oauth2-impersonate-service-account-with-usergmail-com)
- [Google drive api services account view uploaded files to google drive using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302794/google-drive-api-services-account-view-uploaded-files-to-google-drive-using-java)
- [Google Drive changing permissions by service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143544/google-drive-changing-permissions-by-service-account)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I can't still find a solution. Can you give some more details?

Comment: @PeterPenzov have you found a solution to this problem. Many thanks in advance

Comment: No, I haven't yet.